# Adding colors to specific parts of a program C not C++

Tags: c

Is there anyway to do this? im currently using  and the functions system(Color ); but that changes the font and background color of the whole program, how can i change specific parts only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [VT100 escape codes](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes) to add colour to your text output. Then you don't need any external library or program.

Example:

```
printf("This text is \x1b[31mred \x1b[32mgreen \x1b[0mnormal.\n");
```

**Edit:** Escape codes do not work in the Windows command prompt, instead you have to use functions such as [`SetConsoleTextAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Here is an example showing how to use it:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO ConsoleInfo;
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hConsole, &ConsoleInfo);
    int originalAttrs = ConsoleInfo.wAttributes;

    printf("This text is ");
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, FOREGROUND_RED);
    printf("red ");
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, FOREGROUND_GREEN);
    printf("green ");
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, originalAttrs);
    printf("normal\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @vincentbelkin Edited my answer to a Windows-specific solution. It's functionality is standard in Windows, so still no external libraries or programs needed.

Comment: Can't find a table for the colors though.. tried FOREGROUND_BLACK and FOREGROUND_WHITE it didn't work.

Comment: @vincentbelkin See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682088%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_character_attributes) for the possible attributes. Unfortunately black or white doesn't seem to exist.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is. [libcaca](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/libcaca) is a widely supported text-based graphics library, maybe you can find it useful.